# div floating left

Tags: html, css

I work on a page where i want a lot of columns.
The columns should float left, and there should never be a column under a column.
(and if it's possible no scrollbar, just make the columns that exceed the screen impossible to access).

Atm, my second column goes under my first instand of next to it.

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="menu">
    </div>

    <div id="book">

        <div id="column1" class="column_n">
        </div>

        <div id="column2" class="column_n">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 20px;

}

.column_n {
    width: 480px;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: They show side by side for me. http://jsfiddle.net/hTJnX/. Just make sure the 'Result' pane is wide enough to hold both divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position: relative, float left (for sorting columns left to each other)
overflow: hidden; for hiding the overflow of the body;
auto: for wrapping using same length dimension as child element.

Comment: I'm guessing you will need to consider using overflow-x and overflow-y properties) check out w3Schools for more info

Answer (score 2):

It because you need to find the right `width` and `margin` values for your divs:

An ex:

http://jsfiddle.net/e9a7w/1/

and this is how it should be if your `#book` or `body` has a width of `960px`

http://jsfiddle.net/e9a7w/2/

Answer (score 0):

for floating left is working but height of column_n is small 
+ for the problem scrolling

Answer (score 0):

There does not seems to be any problem with your code, apart from the width of the div :
http://jsfiddle.net/XrY8U/

I like to put background-color to my css when I debug, or use chrome dev tools to see the size of the elements.

Most likely, you do not have 2*480 + 4*20 = 1040 px of width available for your columns. Usually websites are designed to be contained in 940 or 960 px.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you have a given amount of columns and only the columns that fit in the browser window should be shown.

If you can set the heights of your columns (and its containers) you can use an overflow on the book div. Columns that don't fit are not shown at all (tried in chromium), if you make the browser wider they can come back.
http://jsfiddle.net/rqdzK/1/

If you just want all columns to show on any size of screen you could relative widths. You make sure all widths add up to 100% (although I believe on IE 100% is too much, so take 99.5 or so).
http://jsfiddle.net/MqFRB/2/